# jQuery removing empty divs

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

I found some examples of hiding empty divs in html with jQuery, but I don't think that my code works (well it doesn't since it's not hiding empty divs). So I want to know what's wrong with it. I'm using it in Joomla, so maybe it's the issue with DOM loading, so that the code executes before it's ready, altho there is `(document).ready()` in it so that shouldn't happen. Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) { 
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
        }).remove();
});
}(jQuery)); 
</script>
```

My aim is to get rid of these classes, since they have background in css defined, and if there is no content in it, I don't need them showing.

Where's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the `:empty` selector? `$('.class1, .class2').filter(':empty').remove()`

Comment: Just to debug: could you try and leave out the `.filter(...)` part to check if it's deleting the elements?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `:empty` does fail with whitespace ( or at least it used to). filter approach shown should work

Comment: @charlieftl I had a feeling it may not work. Frankly I couldn't be bothered to check the jQuery source to find out :)

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/rU895/**

Comment: I don't know, it should work, in fact I think it did work at one point :\

Answer (score 0):

Misplaced closing `)` for the closure:

```
(function ($) { 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
        }).remove();
    });
})(jQuery); //<----- MISPLACED )
```

When using a closure `(function( $ ) { ........ })( jQuery );` you really don't need `jQuery.noConflict()`.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/LgX2M/1/)

Comment: Woot, you just made a syntax error, there's nothing missing ?

Comment: My bad there was a misplaced `)` ... corrected now.

Comment: And it's not misplaced either

Comment: I am open to learning ... please educate me @adeneo. I use this form all the time. Are u saying it's correctly presented by the OP?

Comment: I'm saying it doesn't matter, `(function{})()` or `(funtion{}())` is the same

Comment: Yeah, when I deleted ) I got 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;' :\

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` is for joomla, otherwise bad stuff happens :D